# Enviar texto via form e tranformalo em link via PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de fazer com que o texto escrito em um form fosse adicionado a um link e ao clicar no "button" ele direcionasse para o link gerado.

Por exemplo.

No forme o usuário coloca "tobias" e ao clicar no button ele é direcionado para http://tobias.dominio.com.br.

Não sei se consigo explicar melhor.

Comment: Já tentou algum código? Poste o código para gente analisar.

Comment: então na verdade ainda não pq não tenho ideia de onde começar.
Se fosse o oposto eu faria um "gato".

Por exemplo, eu enviaria a $url via get ($url=$_GET['url'];) e na outra colocaria header("Location: redireciona.php?url=$url");

Comment: É só utilizar JS. Ao pressionar o botão você pegar o conteúdo do INPUT, monta uma URL e da um redirect.

Comment: Mas como faria isso em js?
Sei como redirecionar mas pegar o conteudo e adicionar a url já n sei.
Meio novato.

Comment: e por exemplo, caso a url não exista deste modo ele vai carregar a página errada do mesmo modo, correto?

Comment: Precisa mesmo ser feito via php? um simples redirect pode ser feito no javascript. Assim evitaria tráfego e processos no servidor. Independente de ser um processo muito pequeno.

Comment: Poderia ser qualquer linguagem porem se for só em JS seria melhor, mas mesmo assim eu não saberia fazer.
Por exemplo, se desse para deixar o form sempre fixo na página e carregar em um iframe seria perfeito, mas ai ferraria mais.
Como eu não sei fazer acho que seria demais ficar pedindo tanta coisa.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

/**
 * Verifica se a url passada existe fazendo uma requisição a ela e caso ela retorne http code 200, significa que ela existe.
 */
function checkUrl($url) {

  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($curl);
  return $httpCode == 200;

}

if (isset($_REQUEST['txt_url'])) {

  $link = 'http://' . $_REQUEST['txt_url'] . '.dominio.com.br';

  if (checkUrl($link)) {
      header('Location: ' . $link);
  } else {
      echo 'Pagina nao existe.';
  }

}

?>

<form action="" method="post">

  <label for="txt_url">Seu texto:</label>
  <input type="text" name="txt_url" value="">

  <input type="submit" value="Ok">

</form>
```

Comment: Funcionou, tks!

Tem como (isso acho q não é possível) saber se a URL é existente?
Caso não seja ele informa que o subdomínio esta errado?

Ex: subdominioexiste.dominio.com.br -> ele vai para a página
     subdominioinexistente.dominio.com.br -> ele fica na página mas avisa que o o dominio não existe.

Comment: Ou melhor, ele abrir em um iframe, assim posso manter uma barra sempre ativa para retornar.

Comment: Adicionei a função checkUrl que verifica se a url existe, verifica se dessa forma resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name"subdomain" value="">
    <input type="submit" name"ok" value="Enviar">
</form>

<?php
    if($_POST["ok"]) { // Se clicar no botão submit...
        $subdomain = $_POST["subdomain"]; // Pega valor via post e passa para variável.
        if($subdomain != "") { // Se variável não for vazia...
            header('Location: http://'.$subdomain.'.dominio.com.br'); // Redireciona.
        } else { // Se variável for campo vazio...
            echo "Campo vazio!"; // Imprime na tela.
        }
    }
```